# HTML iFrames to open and close for every 10 secs

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to create a HTML  Webpage with that close and open iFrames for every 10 secs,i've 5 iFrames to open and close for every 10 secs. can someone help or please suggest, i'm a newbie and  learning  too

Assistance and solution

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

this code will close and open iFrames for every 10 secs;

```js
const addIframe = () => {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.id = "testIframe";
  iframe.src = "https://www.example.com/";
  iframe.height = 300;
  iframe.width = "100%";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  // remove the old iframe
  let oldIframe = document.getElementById("testIframe");
  oldIframe && oldIframe.remove();
  //add the new iframe
  addIframe();
}, 10000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```